# How to push my data in another array in jQuery without appending NAN to results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays in my jQuery, and what I want to do is pushing first array's data to other array in my required format: For example below are my array's given:

```
var mine = [
{"new":"new"},
{"old":"old"}
];

var mynew = [];
```

Now I want to put my `mine` array's data to `mynew` array in this way.

```
jQuery.each(mine, function () {
               jQuery.each(this, function (name, data) {
                   mynew.push({text:  +"'"+name+"'"+  ',  value: ' +"'"+data+"'"});
               });
            });
```

and my required output should be something like shown below:

```
[
{text: 'new',  value: 'new'}, 
{text: 'old',  value: 'old'}
]
```

I am doing it right I think but result data is some thing like shown below:

```
Object {text: "NaNnew',  value: 'new'"}
```

which is clearly not what I am wanting ... any one to print my desired layout for me please ????

Comment: remove `+"'"` in the beginning. It acts as unary operator and tries to convert operand to number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
jQuery.each(mine, function () {
               jQuery.each(this, function (name, data) {
                   mynew.push({text: name ,  value: data });
               });
            });
```

Comment: wow, life saver you saved my whole day bro ... thanks a lot once again and really liked your answer as  it worked like a charm .... great :)

Comment: you are welcome , but please make this answer accepted! :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue with `javascript` at Question is

```
text:  +"'"+name+"'"+  ',  value: ' +"'"+data+"'"
```

The quotes are not needed. You are already retrieving the value `data`, which in this case is a string. `name` is the `index` of the current element of the array, not the value. You can use the pattern at `javascript` at Question by substituting the below line for the above line

```
mynew.push({text:data, value:data});
```

---

Note, nested `$.each()` calls are not necessary to return expected result. You can use `Array.prototype.map()`, `Object.keys()`

```js
var mine = [
  {"new":"new"},
  {"old":"old"}
];

var mynew = mine.map(function(obj) {
  var value = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];
  return {text:value, value:value}
});

console.log(mynew);
```

Alternatively using `.map()`, object destructuring, computed property, for `"new"` property, where `new` operator is a reserved word in `javascript`, arrow function

```js
var mine = [
  {"new":"new"},
  {"old":"old"}
];

var mynew = mine.map(({["new"]:n, old:o}) => ({text:(n||o), value:(n||o)}));

console.log(mynew);
```

Comment: why use `$.map` when you can use `Array#map`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
jQuery.each(mine, function () {
      jQuery.each(this, function (name, data) {
              mynew.push({ text: name, value: data});
       });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `NaN` is a result of evaluating `+"'"` which tried to convert `'` to number evaluating unary `+` operator. That being said, you <strike>don't have to</strike>  **shouldn't** create Objects this way using string concatenation!

```
{text:  (+"'") + (name) + ("'") +  (',  value: ') + ("'") + (data) + ("'") }
//{text: "NaName',  value: 'data'"}
```

this doesn't even create a `key` for value, instead just have `text` key having a long string.

---

Use the simple object creation syntax.

```
mynew.push({text:name,  value:data});
```

You can always use `JSON.stringify` later if you want to convert Object to string.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator) for Array.filter. Notice in particular the arguments to the callback:

Function to test each element of the array. Invoked with arguments (element, index, array). Return true to keep the element, false otherwise.
So in your case arr is the element (and poorly named, hence your confusion). Filter loops through your array and for every item it calls you callback passing in the element at the current position as arr.

As others have pointed out in the comments, the logic of your filter callback is actually flawed for negative values, but that may not be an issue if you know that your array will never contain negative values (but that can be a dangerous thing to assume).

And, of course, internally, this is looping through your array. You can't filter your (unsorted) array without touching each element in the array. Look at the polyfil in the link to get an idea of how it might work (might because this is an implementation detail that may differ with different javascript engines, but will no doubt involve a loop somewhere), it loops through your array, calls the callback (note the arguments) and if the callback returns true, it gets pushed onto a results array.